# Is it possible to associate custom test with TFS/MTM Test case?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, vsix, vstest

I have created a VSIX based test adapter using visual studio test platform(vstest) API. It will read my custom test item(in xml) where my test information is there and it will enable the unit test explorer in visual studio to list my tests written in custom test file. (I referred the following blog to create the adapter
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter/#)

I am able to get my custom tests discovered under Unit Test Explorer. But I am not able to associate those tests with TFS/MTM manual test cases. When I right click the test case, the "Associate to Test Case" option is disabled.

Is it possible to get that option enabled to associate with a manual TFS test case ?

NOTE: I am able to associate a .net based unit test method by this way. My VS version is 15.9.2